# What's the proper way to use sheet_name=None on pandas read_excel() to concatenate multiple sheets in a dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

As seen on [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html?highlight=read_excel#pandas.read_excel)

> Specify None to get all sheets.
>
> None -> All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that has 4 sheets, named place_one, place_two, place_tree, place_four

So if I use read_excel like this:

```
dfs_collection = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=None)
```

and then call:

```
dfs_collection.keys()
```

the result will be:

```
odict_keys(['place_one', 'place_two', 'place_tree', 'place_four'])
```

Since all sheets have the same variables, I could concatenate the DFs with:

```
concatenated = pd.concat([dfs_collection.get('place_one'),
                          dfs_collection.get('place_two'),
                          dfs_collection.get('place_tree'),
                          dfs_collection.get('place_four')])
```

But this way I can't (or can't see a way to) identify the origin of the observation.

A way to hard code this would be:

```
df_one = dfs_collection.get('place_one')
df_one['place'] = 'place_one'
...
df_four = dfs_collection.get('place_four')
df_four['place'] = 'place_four'
```

and then:

```
concatenated = pd.concat([df_one,..., df_four])
```

Which would work fine, but looks ugly and demands that I know beforehead the number of sheets and the sheets names.

What would be a pythonic or prettier way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by *the origin of the observation*?

Comment: I mean the sheet where the observation (row) came from, i.e, place_one, place_two on the example.

Comment: you need to add some sample data, otherwise is quite hard to understand the situation. also the title of your question don't quite match the issue you're having

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Yuca, I acknowledge the question was badly framed. As it has an answer that solves the problem, I'll change the title to better suit the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pd.read_excel()` with `sheet_name=None` returns an `OrderedDict`, you can pass that directly to `pd.concat()` by simply doing:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=None))
```

This allows for any number of sheets to be concatenated into a single MultiIndex dataframe, without specifying the number in advance. Note that I'm using `header=None`, since my sample Excel file does not include column headers. See a screenshot below of one sheet (my file has four sheets with the following names `['place_one','place_two','place_three','place_four']`):

[image]

Then `df` corresponds to:

```
               0  1
place_four  0  a  1
            1  b  2
            2  c  3
            3  d  4
            4  e  5
            5  f  6
place_one   0  a  1
            1  b  2
            2  c  3
            3  d  4
            4  e  5
            5  f  6
place_three 0  a  1
            1  b  2
            2  c  3
            3  d  4
            4  e  5
            5  f  6
place_two   0  a  1
            1  b  2
            2  c  3
            3  d  4
            4  e  5
            5  f  6
```

Which I can then query like so, considering it is a MultiIndex dataframe:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['place_four',:], :]
```

Which gives:

```
              0  1
place_four 0  a  1
           1  b  2
           2  c  3
           3  d  4
           4  e  5
           5  f  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) in each item of your `pd.concat` call:

**Long Form**

```
concatenated = pd.concat([dfs_collection.get('place_one').assign(place = 'place_one'),
                          dfs_collection.get('place_two').assign(place = 'place_two'),
                          dfs_collection.get('place_tree').assign(place = 'place_tree'),
                          dfs_collection.get('place_four').assign(place = 'place_four')])
```

**Short Form** with list comprehension

```
concatenated = pd.concat([d.assign(place = k) for k, d in dfs_collection.items()])
```