# Iterate through all sheets of all workbooks in a directory

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I am trying to combine all spreadsheets from all workbooks in a directory into a single df. I've tried with `glob` and with `os.scandir` but either way I keep only getting the first sheet of all workbooks.
First attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

workbooks = glob.glob(r"\mydirectory\*.xlsx")
list = []
for file in workbooks:
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index = True)
    list.append(df)
dataframe = pd.concat(list, axis = 0)
```

Second attempt:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
path = r"\mydirectory\"
with os.scandir(path) as files:
    for file in files:
        data = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = None)
        df = df.append(data)
```

I think the issue lies with the `for` loop but I'm too inexperienced to pin down the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thx!!!

Comment: Please use something else than `list` as a variable btw.

Comment: I've only used it here in the example, not in the actual code. Apologies for the confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you have written correctly, you want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# list of workbooks in directory
workbooks = glob.glob(r"\mydirectory\*.xlsx")
l = []

# for each file in list
for file in workbooks:
    # Class for file allows for retrieving sheet names
    xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)    
    # concatenate DataFrames created from each sheet in the file
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, sheet) for sheet in xl_file.sheet_names], ignore_index=True)
    # append to list
    l.append(df)
# concatenate all file DataFrames to one DataFrame.
dataframe = pd.concat(l, axis=0)
```

This loops through the sheets within the Excel file for the concatenation, the only difference to what you had already written.

## Alternative:

Alternatively, without needing to first find the sheet names, the dictionary created by `pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)` can used.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# list of workbooks in directory
workbooks = glob.glob(r"\mydirectory\*.xlsx")
l = []

# for each file in list
for file in workbooks:
    # concatenate the dictionary of dataframes from pd.read_excel
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
    l.append(df)
# concatenate all file DataFrames to one DataFrame.
dataframe = pd.concat(l, axis=0)
```

A good explanation/example of the use of `sheet_name=None` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990562/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-sheet-name-none-on-pandas-read-excel-to-concatena#:%7E:text=Since%20pd.read_excel%20%28%29%20with%20sheet_name%3DNone%20returns%20an%20OrderedDict%2C,MultiIndex%20dataframe%2C%20without%20specifying%20the%20number%20in%20advance.).  In short, the use of this returns a dictionary of DataFrames for each sheet.  This can then be concatenated to one DataFrame, as above, or an individual sheet's DataFrame could be accessed through `dictionary["sheet_name"]`.

Comment: Thanks, it works just perfectly. Would you be so kind to explain what I was doing wrong? I was under the impression that `pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)` would open each and every sheet of each and every file, that would then be concatenated and appended to the list. Is it not the case?

Comment: I have added an alternative above with `sheet_name=None`.  You are correct that you can access all sheets at once, it just returns a dictionary, not a concatenated DataFrame.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the explanation! Just a follow up question: the alternative code you're suggesting is exactly the same as my first attempt, which was not returning the correct result. What I was ending up with was the first sheet of each file, repeated as many times as the total number of sheets in the directory.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that when I was making the edit!  I don't know if the `list` name was causing the problem for you, but by using `l` I didn't have any problems, do you?  So theoretically, you're attempt should have been correct.

Comment: No, as I said I only used `list` here in the example... I have no clue why it didn't work for me, will let you know if I manage to solve the mystery.